# Back to previous page instead of previous url in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I faced a problem where I have some filters on a page. When you filter, the page URL will change and the query string will add to the end of the URL.So when you click on the back button, the page will stay on the current page and will back to the previous query string. What I want is to get back to the previous page which is come from that to the current page.
For example, I am on `/home` page, then I go to `/browse` page, then I filter some items and my URL will `/browse?subject=2` and I filter again and the URL will be changed to `/browse?subject=2&vendor=2`. Now I want to the previous page (I mean `/home`), when I click on the back button I will go to `/browse?subject=2`. I hope I have conveyed what I mean.

Comment: Use `router.replace` instead of `router.push`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but in this case, my route will be destroyed and if I use router.back() function, I will go to the wrong page

Comment: I mean every time you filter, use `router.replace`. That way only one path stays on the history stack so when you click back, you go back to `/home`.

Comment: It worked, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is in your `/browse` page when you are filtering use `router.replace` instead of `router.push` in this way, your filter result won't be added into the browser history and when you try to use `router.back` you would go to the previous page.